# Visual Studio 2010 - "clean only project" is cleaning dependencies too and I cant get it to stop

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a 3 projects and they have a chain of dependencies (1 depends on 2 and 2 depends on 3).   when i "clean only project" from project 1, it cleans all of the stuff generated by project 2 (which i need to rebuild project 1).  I simply can't figure out why project 1 is deleting project 2's data when I am explicitly stating NOT to clean (i am using "only project option)..

Rebuild solution also causes problems, basically anytime project 1 is "cleaned" it also cleans project 2...   the only work around is to clean all, then build (not rebuild)  3,2,1  (not cleaning again)

Is this a VS bug?  any ideas would help...

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure where this "only project" option might be - is your VS english, or are you translating a phrase from another language?

Comment: It is in the context menu for a project.  One red flag is wanting to use it all, cleaning a project is a pretty useless activity.  If you find it to be necessary then there's a strong hint that there's something broken in the project dependencies.  Chase that rabbit first.

Comment: Sorry I meant "Project Only"..  right clicking on a project you can perform "project only" actions which basically arent supposed to act on the dependencies of that project.  (for example if you right click and just "rebuild"  it will rebuild all of the dependencies as well but if you "Project Only" rebuild, it will not rebuild the dependencies).   when I rebuild "project only" it seems to wipe out the dependency project as well and then it cant build since its doesn't rebuild that dependency project.

Comment: it looks like something called CoreClean might be cleaning everything up. is this something I can control and customize?  I am using NMAKE with a makefile (this is actually a set of cxxtest projects). I assume theres a way to not "CoreClean" ?  microsoft site is very confusing :(

Answer (score 1):

For me I was able to solve the problem by changing the intermediate directory for the projects. In my setup the different projects(all in the same project directory) had the same intermediate directory (defined in a common property sheet). Even though this directory has nothing to do with the actual output directory for the final library changing it fixed the strange behavior.
This solved the problem:

Property Manager | 
 Common Properties | 
  General | 
   Intermediate Directory | 
     $(ProjectDir)..\obj\$(ProjectName)\$(Configuration)\

This made each project's intermediate directory different, and now in the output directory the libraries of the other projects are not deleted when a rebuild of any one of the them is performed.